# Tengo este error POST http://localhost/api/category 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: laravel, angular, api

hola estoy haciendo un ejercicio y tengo este error en consola del navegador y no me deja guardar categoria el api.
Las tecnologia que uso es laravel para el backend y angular en el frontend. resulta que no me sale ningun problema en el transpilador de la consola . Y he probado también en la petición de url en posmant si el fallo era de ayi pero me funciona correctamente.

Os dejo los archivos adjunto si veis algún fallo.
Este es el codigó del servicio ts (category.service.ts)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Category } from '../models/category';
import { global } from './global';



@Injectable()
export class CategoryService{
    public url: string;

    constructor(
        private _http: HttpClient
    ){
        this.url = global.url;
    }

    create(token, category):Observable<any>{
        let json = JSON.stringify(category);
        let params = 'json =' + json;
       
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-ulrencoded')
                                       .set('Authorization', token);


        return this._http.post(this.url + 'category', params ,{headers:headers});
       
    }
}
```

este el componente de category (Category-new.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router , ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService} from '../../services/user.service';

import { CategoryService} from '../../services/category.service';
import { Category } from '../../models/category'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-new',
  templateUrl: './category-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-new.component.css'],
  providers:[UserService, CategoryService]
})
export class CategoryNewComponent implements OnInit {
  public page_title :string;
  public identity;
  public token;
  public category: Category;
  public status: string;

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _categoryService:CategoryService
  ) { 
    this.page_title ="Crear nueva Categoria";
    this.identity = this._userService.getIdentity();
    this.token = this._userService.getToken();

    this.category = new Category(1,'');
    
  

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmit(form){
    this._categoryService.create(this.token ,this.category).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.status == 'success'){
          this.category = response.category;
          this.status= 'success';

          this._router.navigate(['/inicio']);
        }else{
          
          this.status ='error';
        }
      
      },
      error => {
        this.status='error';
    
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

y esta es la vista de category html

```html
<div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
    <h1>{{page_title}}</h1>
     <p *ngIf="status !='success'">Crear una nueva categoria para el blog 
         </p>
     <hr>
     
    <div class="alert alert-success col-md-5" *ngIf="status =='success'">
       La categoria se ha creado correctamente
     </div>
 
     <div class="alert alert-danger col-md-5" *ngIf="status =='error'">
        La categoria no se han guardado 
     </div>

     <!--FORMULARIO DE CREAR CATEGORYA -->
     <form #categoryForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(categoryForm)"  class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="category.name" required >
            <small *ngIf="!name.valid && name.touched" class="invalid-feedback d-block">
                El nombre de categoria no es valido 
            </small>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="categoryForm.invalid">

     </form>
     
     <br>
 </div>
```

La imagen del fallo que me sale es este desde la consola
por lo que yo he observado no me deja entra en la condición response y me falla
las petición del posmant me sale bien correctament poniendo el token y el json manulmente  con lo que he optado que es posible que falle algo que no veo.
Si me podeís ayudar os lo agradezco mucho
Gracia ante mano
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la imagen de la repuesta del navegador es esta :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agregaste los metadatos?

Comment: que metadatos  Dohko

Comment: las propiedades fileName y fileType

Comment: haciendo un console.log en param me devuelve los datos que pongo en el imput+